# C++ Arrays and elements

Tags: c++

my program is focusing on Array elements for this lab, but I am not sure on how to set my average to a specific number that is requested. Any guidance would be helpful for this post

```
#include "pch.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int arr[10], n, i, max, min, avg;
    cout << "Enter the size of the array: ";
    cin >> n;
    cout << "Enter the elements of the array: ";
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
        cin >> arr[i];
    max = arr[0];
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        if (max < arr[i])
            max = arr[i];
    }
    min = arr[0];
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        if (min > arr[i])
            min = arr[i];
    }
    avg = arr[0];
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        if (avg > arr[i])
            avg = arr[i];
    }
    cout << "Largest element: " << max;
    cout << "Smallest element: " << min;
    cout << "Average element: " << avg;
}
```

Comment: In your term 'average', do you mean the average of the numbers inside array or is it the middle of min and max? Because the computation of your avg variable is not likely the computation for average. Please clarify.

Comment: @BlitzNinja29 the middle of min and max

Comment: so you will display 8 numbers?

Comment: Regarding `int arr[10]`, seek assurances that no user will provide an `n` greater than 10. Personally I recommend checking for it and asking for a different number. Humans are very effective at providing bad numbers. Sometimes maliciously.

Comment: My expectations are that instead of `if (avg > arr[i]) avg = arr[i];` you would sum the numbers and then divide by `n` just as one normally does when computing an average.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using the += operator in your for loop and then dividing by n.

```
float sum = 0;
float avg = 0;
for(i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    sum += arr[i];
}
avg = sum / n;
```

Also, I would recommend using either a float or double instead of using an int for your average because otherwise you're doing integer division which will cut off the decimal. i.e. 5 / 2 = 2